# Two figures in a subfigure

Tags: subfloats

I need to show a total of 8 figures in the same page, combining them in this way:

```
 img1-a img1-b
 img2-a img2-b
   (a)  (b)

 img1-c img1-d
 img2-c img2-d
   (c)  (d)
```

I tried subfigure,

```
\begin{figure*}[tpb]
\centering
\subfigure[]
      {\label{fig:conn}
      \includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth,keepaspectratio]{img1-a}
      \includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth,keepaspectratio]{img1-a}}\hfill

\subfigure[]
//and so on....
```

but I do not understand how to combine two figures to stay on the same column (i.e. figure  img1-a and  img2-a). Maybe forcing the subfigure width? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: did you have a look at the documentation of subfig package http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/ and the subfigure package http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/obsolete/macros/latex/contrib/subfigure/ - I think one of these should solve your problem

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine the images that have to be placed in the same column in the same subfigure with a minipage. I can't get this to work in subfigure, for some particular reason. But this code should give you the output you want with the subfig package.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[tpb]
        \centering
        \subfloat[]{
            \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
                \includegraphics[width=0.98\linewidth, height = 0.2\textheight, keepaspectratio=true]{1a}

                \includegraphics[width=0.98\linewidth, height = 0.2\textheight, keepaspectratio=true]{2a}
            \end{minipage}} 
        \subfloat[]{
            \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
                \includegraphics[width=0.98\linewidth, height = 0.2\textheight, keepaspectratio=true]{1b}

                \includegraphics[width=0.98\linewidth, height = 0.2\textheight, keepaspectratio=true]{2b}
            \end{minipage}} 

        \subfloat[]{
            \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
                \includegraphics[width=0.98\linewidth, height = 0.2\textheight, keepaspectratio=true]{1c}

                \includegraphics[width=0.98\linewidth, height = 0.2\textheight, keepaspectratio=true]{1d}
            \end{minipage}}  
        \subfloat[]{
            \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
                \includegraphics[width=0.98\linewidth, height = 0.2\textheight, keepaspectratio=true]{2c}

                \includegraphics[width=0.98\linewidth, height = 0.2\textheight, keepaspectratio=true]{2d}
            \end{minipage}} 
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Beware of removing whitelines here, as that influences the spacing of the floats.

Comment: tx for answering. I am trying your solution but error is occurring about subfloat.  I have the \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{subfloat}.

Comment: I added my header to the example. It is possible that subfigure and subfloat don't  play nice together.

Comment: @doxsi The only package to use in your case is `subfig`, in my opinion; `subfigure` is obsolete and you're using only its syntax.

Comment: Tx , it works. I just edited because "]" miss in the code

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `subfig` and `floatrow` *with* global caption

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig} %must be loaded before floatrow, since i loads caption
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
\begin{subfloatrow}
\includegraphics{img1-a}\quad
\includegraphics{img1-b}
\end{subfloatrow}

\begin{subfloatrow}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}\label{subfig:a}\includegraphics{img2-a}}{}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}\label{subfig:b}\includegraphics{img2-b}}{}
\end{subfloatrow}
\vspace{10pt}
\begin{subfloatrow}
\includegraphics{img1-c}\quad
\includegraphics{img1-d}
\end{subfloatrow}

\begin{subfloatrow}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}\label{subfig:c}\includegraphics{img2-c}}{}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}\label{subfig:d}\includegraphics{img2-d}}{}
\end{subfloatrow}}
{\caption{now with caption}\label{fig:figures}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Tx, it works (erasing subfigure package). But I am esperimenting that no global  caption appear using your solution.

Comment: I noticed that too and wondered why, but since your sketch didn't had one either I stopped wondering why